# If we use DataGrid in windows phone 7 will it create a objection in certification of app?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

I am using the DataGrid in my windows phone 7 app and I am pleased with the way it looks but I wanted to know?

1. If we use DataGrid in windows phone 7 app will it create any objection in certification of my app?
2. Is Datagrid Against the UI guidelines of windows phone 7 app Certification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you've implemented the DataGrid ... there's lots of good metro looking DataGrids within metro style windows apps, so it can be done well.

As for their guidelines and rejecting your app ... their guidelines are just that; guidelines ... there's many apps that don't look like good "Metro" apps, but they still make it into the marketplace, so you should be fine.

Basically you should be more worried about creating a create experience for your users, if you do that your app will do well.